# Laravel Collections. forget() on nested key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-collection

Is it possible to use some neat Laravel collection method similar to `forget()`, that will work with nested arrays.

Here is an example of what I want.

I have such a `Collection` instance:

[image]

And I want to drop `coordinates` column (all items are identical) in a similar way to

```
$cities->forget('cities', 2) // (second parameter is not real, it's a "nested level" and I took it from my head as example of what I want)
```

As an answer I'd like to receive some existing `Collection` method or a `Collection` macro, that will work in one line.

All other "more than one line options" with `unset()` and `map()` won't be better, than what I have now :)

Comment: You can extend the collection in laravel if you want to make it this way. Other way the unset is fastest

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek Thank you for the answer. Yes, I know about Collections macroses, but I though, that there could be a more obvious solution. I like neat and small pipelines.